# cookies handling on webrequest and response

Tags: c#

I have created a application that has a function `mainpost`. It is created to post data on a https sites. Here I want to handle cookies in this function. How can I do this task?

```
public string Mainpost(string website, string content)
{
    // this is what we are sending
    string post_data = content;

    // this is where we will send it
    string uri = website;

    // create a request
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
    WebRequest.Create(uri); request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.Method = "POST";

    // turn our request string into a byte stream
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

    // this is important - make sure you specify type this way
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    // now send it
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    // grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status
    // code
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string str = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) object and set the `CookieContainer` property of each `HttpWebRequest` to the `CookieContainer` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [CookieContainer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) between requests.

If you maintain the same cookie container the cookies will be resent with future requests.